# Unlock feature in app based on signed-in user via Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase to authenticate my app users by signing in with their Google account. I am looking for a way to unlock a specific feature in my app for specific users. Example: Once I see signed-in user Tom in my Firebase console, I would like to unlock a "hidden" feature in my app just for Tom. Once I unlock this feature manually in my console, the feature gets unlocked in Tom's app instance. All other users cannot see this feature:
[image]
Is somethink like that possible via Firebase?

Comment: For that, you have to use `Firebase Realtime Database` or `Firestore`.  Store each user under `users` node like `/users/{uid}/`. Then you can update the value of child under the user node for any user like `/users/{uid}/feature`.

Comment: store your users in Real Time Database once logged In, you just need to add a `/authUsers/{uid}/feature_name:hidden` or `unlocked` let's say.